# How to use ximea api with conda on linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, ximea

I am unable to use the Ximea API (python) on linux. The documentation makes it seem like I only have to install the software package ([documentation link 1/2](https://www.ximea.com/support/wiki/apis/XIMEA_Linux_Software_Package#Installation)) and the library will be available for import in any python script ([documentation link 2/2](https://www.ximea.com/support/wiki/apis/Python_inst_linux)). This is not the case. In windows, one can just copy-past the library from the installation folder. This is not possible in linux : the folder `/opt/XIMEA` does contain the python example scripts, but it does not contain the library folder itself.

Where can I find the python library folder for linux? How should I go about installing this in conda or another virtual environment?

Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was provided to me via the XIMEA helpdesk.

> Hello,
>
> You are right that the python xiapi is not usable after installation
> without further steps to ensure so in some cases. There seems to be a
> compatibility issue with the latest version of python and our software
> package installation script, because of which the files aren't copied
> correctly to the right location. We will work on analyzing and fixing
> this, and to do so, we would appreciate if you could provide us with a
> few more information. Please send us a xiCOP report, version of Python
> you are using, and the output of the software package installation
> script if possible. These may help us find out where exactly the
> problem is. Thank you for your feedback, it is helping us greatly to
> improve our products.
>
> Meanwhile, in the next steps I'll help you copy the files manually to
> get the API to work right now:
>
> 1. Locate the downloaded and unzipped folder "XIMEA_Linux_SP" from the first step of our software package installation guide (for me it was
>    on Desktop but this may differ for you).
> 2. Navigate to the /XIMEA_Linux_SP/package/api/Python/ folder and go to either "v2" or "v3" folder according to the python version you're
>    using. There you'll find a folder "ximea" inside of which are the
>    xiapi library files.
> 3. Locate the folder for python packages on your system (for me it was at /lib/python3/dist-packages/ but it may differ for you).
> 4. Copy the whole "ximea" folder from step 2. into your python packages folder (you will probably encounter permission issues, please
>    use sudo or similar workaround to solve this).
> 5. Your python scripts should work now.

I found the right folder by using `conda info`. This way I could find my conda environments in `/home/jan/miniconda3/envs/<ENV NAME>/lib/python3.10/`. By simply copy-pasting the `ximea` folder to this folder, everything worked.